# Временная таблица SQL

Tags: sql

теперь я еще со временной табличкой не разберусь. В селекте выводятся все записи как положено, а в основную таблицу добавляется только одна. Может не в том порядке я что делаю, вот так вкратце это выглядит:

```
create table #table (id int,a int,b int,c int)
SET @i=1
WHILE @i<=100
BEGIN
/*расчет переменных*/
insert into #table (id int,a int,b int,c int) values (@i,@aa,@bb,@cc)
SET @i=@i+1
END
insert into Table values (@i,@aa,@bb,@cc)
select * from #table order by a
drop table #table
```

Comment: insert into Table values (@i,@aa,@bb,@cc)

эта строка не в цикле
либо в цикл ее нужно переписать, либо делать SELECT INTO из временной таблицы в основную

Comment: @petya, а как в данном случае будет выглядеть SELECT INTO?

Answer (score 1):

Последний запрос должен выглядеть так:

```
insert into Table select * from #table
```

Comment: @msi, а тогда появляется ошибка типа 
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint....., но при выполнении селекта ее нет. Никак нельзя ее пропустить при заполнении, ведь в селекте все выводится хорошо в отсортированном порядке?

Comment: ну это может означать только одно: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint.

заполняй значит и соседнюю таблицу правильными значениями

Comment: > Никак нельзя ее пропустить при заполнении, ведь в селекте все выводится хорошо в отсортированном порядке?

Ограничения помогают вам не превратить базу в кучу мусора. Но если вам именно этого и нужно добиться, удалите ограничение FOREIGN KEY. Догадываюсь, о чем будет следующий вопрос. :-)

Comment: @msi, а в этом случае insert into Table select * from #table
 order by не предусмотрен? таблица-то заполняется, но без сортировки.

Comment: Каждый следующий вопрос демонстрирует все большие глубины вашего незнания. Зачем вы используете реляционные системы, если вам нужен упорядоченный набор записей? Или вас злой "препод" заставил?
Сейчас становятся популярными базы данных NoSQL. Там вы не испытаете подобных затруднений. :-)